# Connection between Two Cruds

Tags: laravel

I want to send data from a Controller to an other one. From Client Crud to Reservation Crud. With this form i want send to booking method in ReservationController to associate a room with the client.

```
  <form action="{{Route('reservation.booking', $room->id, $client->id)}}" method="POST">
     @csrf
     @method('get')
     <select class="roomname" name="roomname">
        <option selected>Elige habitacion</option>
        <option value="{{$rooms[0]->id}}">ESTANÇA DEL PUIGRACIÓS</option>
        <option value="{{$rooms[1]->id}}">ESTANÇA DE SANT CRISTÒFOL</option>
        <option value="{{$rooms[2]->id}}">ESTANÇA (DÚPLEX) DEL ROCACENTELLA</option>
     </select>                        
    <input type="submit" value="Reservar habitación" class = "btn btn-primary">
  </form>
```

```
    public function booking(Room $room, Client $client)
      {
       //dd($client);

       $room->client()->associate($client);
       $room->save();

       return redirect(route('reservation.create'));
      }
The route definition:

Route::get('/reservation/{reservation}/booking','ReservationController@booking')
->name('reservation.booking');
```

And I got this message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `rooms` (`client_id`, `updated_at`,
>   `created_at`) values (?, 2020-05-10 16:21:19, 2020-05-10 16:21:19))

[image]

Comment: Can you `dd($room);` and add the content to your question? I don't see anything related to a `name` field in your question

Comment: Can we see the route definition for this route? Your model binding is not working, when that happens it creates an empty Room object and you are trying to save it.